# Double groupby mean and adding a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hoping that this is not been asked before. I am trying to groupby two columns and add the mean as a new column.

I get this message, without me being able to check how can I correct it, or if the code is actually correct

> **main**:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using
>   .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

If there is a way to bypass this warning, or to correct it. Please not that the DF is really  big (half a million rows). Any help would be nice.

```
average_stand['mean'] = average_stand.groupby(['branch_id','bill']).transform('mean',numeric_only = False)


    customer_id  branch_id   bill       mean
144    1            1       10           13
145    1            1       16           13
146    1            2       16           16
147    2            2       14           16.5
148    2            2       19           16.5
```

Comment: Your df is subset of others ? try look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Agree with @WeNYoBen . wherever you are creating a slice to create this dataframe, try to assign it by calling `.copy()`

Comment: Indeed, .copy() worked. Thank you both.